# Why is this error happening in bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin, sh

Using cygwin, I have

```
currentFold="`dirname $0`"
echo ${currentFold}...
```

This outputs ...gdrive/c/ instead of /cygdrive/c/...

Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is stored in DOS format, with a carriage return followed by linefeed (sometimes written "\r\n") at the end of each line; unix uses just a linefeed ("\n") at the end of lines, and so bash is mistaking the carriage return for part of the command. When it sees

```
currentFold="`dirname $0`"\r
```

it dutifully sets currentFold to "/cygdrive/c/\r", and when it sees

```
echo ${currentFold}...\r
```

it prints "/cygdrive/c/\r...\r". The final carriage return doesn't really matter, but the one in the middle means that the "..." gets printed on top of the "/cy", and you wind up with "...gdrive/c/".

Solution: convert the script to unix format; I believe you'll have the `dos2unix` command available for this, but you might have to look around for alternatives. In a pinch, you can use

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' /path/to/script
```

(see http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5088/convert-files-from-dos-line-endings-to-unix-line-endings). Then switch to a text editor that saves in unix format rather than DOS.

Comment: Your explanation seems very logical. However I think my file is already in utf8 with \n endings. I am using notepad++ and I can go to "show end of line" in "view->show symbol" and it only shows "lf" in the end of lines. Is notepad++ wrong, or what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: I had gone to edit->EOL conversion -> unix format, and it removed CRLF to just LF. But it still shows this weird echo error

Comment: Try printing the script with `cat -v /path/to script` -- that should show any carriage returns as "^M". Also, within the script try `echo "${currentFold}..." | od -tc` (I think that option is available in Cygwin) to see exactly what's being printed.

Comment: cat -v doesn't show any \r. However od -tc shows /cygdrive/c/\r...\n where is that \r coming from ?

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty much stumped where it's coming from. Ok, one more test: try running the script with `bash -x /path/to/script | cat -v` -- the `-x` will make bash print each command before it executes it, and `cat -v` should make the carriage return visible.

Comment: Instead of using dirname, I used currentFold="${0%/*}", and this one doesn't produce a \r\n but just \n. Any idea why ?

Comment: Yeah I got it, I was using the windows 'dirname' command instead of the /bin/dirname command :). Replacing dirname by /bin/dirname works

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Gordon Davisson's anwer.

I am also using Cygwin. In my case this happened because my Git for Windows was configured to `Checkout Windows-style, commint Unix style line endings`.

This is the default option, and was breaking all my cloned shell scripts.

I reran my git setup and changed to `Checkout as-is, commit Unix-style line endings` which prevented the problem from happening at all.

[image]